# understanding how to look up ext js docs (panel.item.each)

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to understand how to read the ext js docs to find what I'm looking for.

For example, I have a panel, var panel = somepanel.
Now I want to do a for each on this panel.
I think it should go something like
panel.items.each()... but what can I use as parameters?

Where in the docs can I find what the parameters should be in a panel items foreach?

this is what I found following your instructions.. what do I actually type in?
myDetailsPanel.items.each(function (item, index, len), scope {

???  I am getting a syntax error[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

- Start with [`Panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel)
- Find the [`items`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-property-items) property.
- Click the type of [`items`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.util.ItemCollection) ([`Ext.util.ItemCollection`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.util.ItemCollection))
- Find the [`each`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.util.AbstractMixedCollection-method-each) method.

---

So you can use it like this:

```
myDetailsPanel.items.each(function(item){

// ...

}, this);
```

Comment: I put a screenshot above... what would I actually type in?